# Polygons joining together to make similar polygons

Tags: contest-math, polygons

I was given the below question in a math competition a few weeks ago.

[image]

I was bit confused about the wording of the problem and what was meant by the word "similar" in the given context. I tried doing part (a) and came up with the below shape.

[image]

Is this what they are asking for? Also, I tried doing part (b) however, I could not find any when n is greater than 4. Any ideas?

EDIT: I think I've finally found one where n=5!!
[image]

Now, back to part (b). For which n? Do we now have to try n=6?

Thank you.

Comment: The big polygon is not similar to the little ones.  Similar means that one is a scaled version of the other, and there is no uniform scaling factor that will give the big from the little.

Comment: Your shape is not correct, although the small ones are okay , the bigger shape must also contains "bigger" $4$ cells

Comment: I think to be similar they must be proportional.  Yours, I'm afraid is not.  You smaller piece is 1 by 2 by 3.  Your bigger one is 2 by 3 by 5.  It needs to be 2 by 4 by 6.

Comment: But you *can* rearrange four ells into a bigger el with *4* els.  So the el is amazing.  In general to make a figure n times as big you'll need n^2 of the smaller ones to make the bigger one.

Comment: To make a polygon n times bigger you need $n^2$ smaller polygons.  So to make a L that is proportionally 4 times bigger, you will need 16 smaller Ls.  You just need to add 2 more Ls and stick them on the left hand side.

Comment: A five polygon that is a 2x2 square with a fifth 1x1 square sticky out the side is an amazing polygon with 5 cells.

Comment: Thanks.  I now understand what was meant by "similar".

Comment: A similarity transform is the combination of a rotation and an isotropic scaling. In this particular case, the rotation must be a multiple of 90° and the scale factor an integer.

Comment: Is mirroring allowed ?

Comment: The question does not mention anything about mirroring so I'm not sure. Sorry. If mirroring is not allowed, I guess I could just readjust the shapes such that are not mirror images in the diagram above for n=5.

Answer (score 2):

For the first this is the solution

[image]

Comment: Nice! :) I think I've found n=5 (I edited my question). But... other than simply trying a lot of number of cells, I don't see any way to do part (b) :(

Answer (score 2):

For even $n=2k$, take a shape formed by a column of $k+1$ squares next to one of  $k-1$ squares; for odd $n=2k+1$, $k+1$ next to $k$.

Assemble two copies to form a rectangle of size $2\times n$. Assemble $n\times2$ such pairs to form a square of size $2n\times2n$. Then arrange $n$ squares to form the original shape, for a total of $4n^3$ copies.